# android apps not getting dowloaded from playstore

Tags: google-play-store

today i tried to download an application from play store. but instead it showed the error message not enough store space in device memory. i tried to search the solution for it on net. 
so i did few things like.
1. go to settings> all application> then Google play services clear cache ,clear data , force stop it.
2.  and then do the same thing for Google play store.

but they also didn't work. what should i do.

Comment: What phone? On most Samsungs it helps to: open the dialer, type *#9900# then a menu appears and select the second item: _Delete dumpstate/logcat_ That will free up space from some internal partitions and enable app installs.

Comment: [insufficient-memory-tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) This tag is associated with may questions with similar issues. Have a look at it. If it helps then please answer your question. Otherwise, do an [edit] to let us know what did you try but not worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply there isnt enough storage as stated in the error.

Apps are installed in data patition not your internal sd card. Dont be misleaded by that. There are /cache /data /system partitions .Preinstalled system applications are in read only /system partition. When you install app from play store it will be installed in /data partition and its limited. My 16 GB phone has only 2GB data partition

Try to clear some other applications data

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your data connection is active
2. Make sure Download Manager is turned on
3. Check your device has enough free storage available
4. Clear cache & data
5. Re-install Play Store updates
6. Check for system updates